# How to use WSUS API?

Tags: wsus

Can you tell me or if there is any tutorial on how to use wsus api ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This what you're looking for?

[**Windows Server Update Services 3.0 Class Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744624(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What Squilman said, and

blogcastrepository.com/.../wsus-3-0-api-samples-download.aspx

and

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsus/archive/2007/04/27/wsus-3-developer-s-blog-api-samples.aspx

and

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=805aa009-0c90-4334-a4a1-0c07f9262437&displaylang=en